# asp.net MVC Grid / basic CRUD with grid on same page / parent-child? master-detail?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid, crud

I'm using Asp.net MVC2 and I'm trying to do the following (apologies if I don't have the terms correct):

I have an Order Header + Order Line Items. I would like, on a single "Create New Order" page, allow the user to enter the Order Header Details, followed by a 'panel' to enter an individual Line Items. In that panel, a link or button would then add it to a grid, all on the same page.

The grid, in turn, would have the usual 'delete' action item. The page itself would have a "submit" button to send everything back to the server -- i.e. Order Header + collection of Order Line Items.

Question
How do I do this? What are my options?

I've seen many people recommend jQuery Grid and MVC Contrib Grid. Are these my two best options? Are both of these done on the client-side? What does my controller look like? Namely, does my controller action contain the populated "Order" object with embedded "Item" collection?

If I didn't use the above grids, what's my next option? Would I have to implement my own custom model binding and use for-loops to create the HTML tags and fields for the items?

Your expert guidance is much appreciated,
Thank you.
Ray

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the [telerik MVC grid extensions](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid). It is a true MVC grid conforming to the Model-View-Controller paradigm and you can have server, jQuery ajax or web service binding for it. Tweaking with its integrated features, you will probably get what you are after.